# How to control a scanner from a browser application?

Tags: c#, java, scanning, wia, image-scanner

I know this is a difficult issue, but I'm asked to build an application that allows users to scan pages (from an Automatic Document Feeder) , and upload them into an FTP server. And I should integrate this into a PHP web application.

Any programming language will work, I just want to know how.

I have found a C# library called WIA. Is it the best option I have ?

Can I build a browser application (with Flash or Java) that can interact with the scanner ?

Thanks !

Comment: @Kyle thanks! I was just reading this page. But it says `Note, TWAIN has it's root in 16-Bit Windows! For a more modern API supported on Windows ME/XP, have a look at Windows Image Acquisition (WIA).` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can check out the following sourceforge project called phpSANE.http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/

Essentially need to setup and use [SANE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_Access_Now_Easy) to work with your scanner. You can then use or modify (cause it's open source) phpSANE running on your web server which will then pick up the files and save them to an FTP server.

I'm not sure how you might automatically detect documents put into the Automatic Document Feeder, perhaps there is a way SANE is notified and you can get this use this to call a PH script?